# Правилен ли такой подход решения этой задачи? Чем это грозит в работе?

Tags: javascript, объекты, this

**

```
Создайте объект calculator (калькулятор) с тремя методами:
```

- read() (читать) запрашивает два значения и сохраняет их как свойства
  объекта.
- sum() (суммировать) возвращает сумму сохранённых    значений.
- mul() (умножить) перемножает сохранённые значения и    возвращает
  результат.

**

```js
let calculator = {
  
  a:"", 
  b:"",
  read(){
    this.a=parseInt(prompt("Enter a:", 12));
    this.b=parseInt(prompt("Enter b:", 11));
  },
  sum(){
    return this.a+this.b;
  },
  mul(){
    return this.a*this.b;
  },
};
calculator.read();
alert(calculator.sum());
alert(calculator.mul());
```

То есть правилен ли такое объявление свойств a и b в объекте(хотя код нормально работает)?

**Функция-конструктор**

```js
let Calculator= function(a, b,){
this.a=a;
this.b=b;     
}
Calculator.prototype.read=function() {
        this.a=parseInt(prompt("Enter a:", 12));
        this.b=parseInt(prompt("Enter b:", 11));
      };

Calculator.prototype.sum=
function(){
        return this.a+this.b;
      };
 Calculator.prototype.mul=
 function(){
        return this.a*this.b;
      };

let calculator=new Calculator(0,0);
calculator.read();
alert(calculator.sum());
alert(calculator.mul());
```

Comment: вместо строк стоило их числами инициализировать. методы sum, mul, не соответствуют задаче, потому что ничего не возвращаются

Comment: @Grundy Да я поменяла вышенаписанном коде alert на return(не это я имела ввиду). Я **a:""** , и
  **b:""** , так написала, это правильный подход(это я имела ввиду)?

Comment: _вместо строк стоило их числами инициализировать_

Comment: @Grundy a:1, b:2, так у них будет значение. Я хочу чтоб они были объявлены без инициализации(чтоб они были пустыми). a:null, b:null, так тоже работает. Можно так?

Comment: можно 0 сделать начальным значением.

Comment: И лучше не делать объект calculator, а сделать через класс или функцию-конструктор. Потому что иначе будет тяжело создать несколько калькуляторов на странице.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Я создала функцию-конструктор(код можете увидеть выше). Вы это имели наверное ввиду. Эта так правильна?

Comment: Да, так будет лучше. Разве что, наверное, не надо передавать параметры в конструктор, есть же функция read для считывания параметров.

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko Да, вы правы. Спасибо.